# How to activate and deactivate the User account using express & mongodb?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

instead of deleting the user account from the database I want to deactivate an account to prevent them from login.

```
//Can not capture active field
router.post('/login', loginValidation, async (req, res) => {
  let user = await UserSchema.findOne;

  const { email, password } = req.body;
  console.log('Active = ', active);

  if (!email || !password)
    return res.json({
      status: 'error',
      message: 'Email and password are require',
    });

  const user = await getUserByEmail(email);
  const passFromDB = user && user._id ? user.password : null;

  if (!passFromDB)
    return res.json({ status: 'error', message: 'Wrong Email or Password' });
  console.log(user.name);
  const result = await comparePassword(password, passFromDB);
  if (!result) {
    return res.json({ status: 'error', message: 'Wrong Email or Password' });
  }
})
```

In User Schema I have `active field` with type Boolean to check if the user account is activate or deactivate. I can deactivate and activate from the admin route, but when it came to validation from the user login route as I show code above, the problem is I don't have any way to capture `active field` to check if the account is activated or not when user tries to log in.

```
//user schema
onst UserSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    //unique: true,
    maxLength: 50,
  },
password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
active: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
})
```

```
//admin deactivate and activate user accounts
router.patch(
  '/account',
  userAuthorization,
  roleBase(['admin']),
  async (req, res) => {
    await UserSchema.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: req.userId },
      { $set: { active: req.body.active } },
      { new: true }
    )
      .then((account) => {
        if (account)
          return res.json({ msg: 'User account deactivate successfully!' });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        return res
          .status(500)
          .json({ msg: 'Unable to deactivate account', error: err.message });
      });
  }
);
```

Any suggestion or idea?

Comment: if i am understanding your question properly. You just need to check for if user.active is true in your login method.

Comment: Yes, you are correct but how to capture that user.active at the user API, because we don't want to show it on the front end for the end user login form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it in this way. By adding a check statement inside the router async function.

```
router.post('/login', loginValidation, async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
    if (!email || !password)
    return res.json({
      status: 'error',
      message: 'Email and password are required',
    });
  const user = await User.find({email})
//Now you have the user data in user variable.
  console.log(`Active = ${user.active}`) 
  if(user.active !== true){
  //you can add your actions
  }
});
```

Thanks